# How to create an identical conda environment on a different architecture computer?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda, miniconda

I was working with Jupyter notebook in miniconda3 py37_4.8.3 distribution on a 32-bit operating system. Now I want to transfer the notebooks so that I can access them from a 64-bit operating system computer. I have created an environment on the new machine with
`conda env create -f environment_name.yml` as specified by https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file, so now I have all the packages I need in the new computer. But when I try to build an identical conda environment in **the new machine** using `conda create --name environment_name --file spec-file.txt` as specified in the above link, I get the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata <repodata.json>: done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
```

Followed by lines like

```
-defaults/win-32:: something else
```

I suspect that this is due to the difference in architectures, I want to know if it is simply impossible to do this, or if you know of a suitable and friendly way to do it. Thanks

Comment: The conda documentation there does say "An explicit spec file is not usually cross platform...On other platforms, the packages specified might not be available or dependencies might be missing ...". Is it just the Jupyter notebooks you want to replicate ? Is there an issue with just moving them to a new environment?

Comment: Yes, I did read that, yes I just need the notebooks in Jupyter, then I think I could download and upload, I wanted to avoid the hassle